# Issue with Installing CatBoost Version 0.24.4 in VSCode

Tags: installation, version, python-3.8, catboost

I'm currently encountering an issue while attempting to install CatBoost version 0.24.4 using a requirements.txt file in VSCode. My Python version is 3.8.3. Here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost==0.24.4 (from versions: 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for catboost==0.24.4
```

Despite specifying version 0.24.4 in the requirements.txt file, it seems that VSCode is unable to locate a compatible distribution. I've verified that this version exists, so I'm unsure why it's not being recognized.

Could you please assist me in understanding why VSCode is unable to install this specific version of CatBoost? Additionally, if there are any troubleshooting steps I can take to resolve this issue, I'd greatly appreciate your guidance.

Thank you for your help.

I attempted to install CatBoost version 0.24.4 using a requirements.txt file in VSCode. I expected the installation to proceed without errors since version 0.24.4 was specified in the requirements.txt file. However, I encountered an error message stating that no matching distribution was found for CatBoost version 0.24.4.